# can't make window.location.reload() inside the ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, yahoo-api

**Problem**

I am not able to refresh the page with **window.location.reload()** which is used inside the success call made to yahoo.

Any hints how it can be fixed.
The whole of the code is working fine it is making call to cse server getting contents from there saving on yahoo. but i have to manually refresh the page to bring the contents. I want it to be automatic so I used **window.location.reload()** but thats not working. Any suggestions how it can be done. The function below is actually a function for a button.

Comment: please post the script as description does not provide enough details

Comment: Does the json validate? jsonlint.com

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. You're saying the var request = Yahoo... works just fine, you get that response back. But then you say you send that response to server 2 via POST. I don't see that second call. I do see a GET ajax call, but you don't pass the data along. Also, why are you using xmlHttp directly when you have the YAHOO.util stuff around?

Comment: Are you running into cross-site scripting errors with the two servers used?

Comment: @ justkt I don't know  that it is cross-site scripting error since the message is sent but I never get response back I just get Error as the contents...  since I am using the javascript to take contents from cse server and then send those contents to yahoo server.

Comment: did you tried to return exactly postData from the first application, it seams like yahoo requires more then just json (key=value pairs, with only one having json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem, right there.

If your script is running from the CSE server's domain, you cannot send data to the yahoo server. This is javascript's main limitations. Likewise, if running off of the yahoo domain, you can send data to it, but cannot send data to the CSE server, unless it is part of the yahoo domain.

Would work:
Get data from blahblahblah.yahoo.com, then send data to somedomain.yahoo.com

Would not work:
Get data from blahblahblah.somesite.com and send data to somedomain.yahoo.com

Main point, if you're getting data from "csce.unl.edu" and running off of that domain (aka running your script in a browser window from that domain), you can only send data to a site that ends with ".unl.edu". So you can send or receive from "test.unl.edu", but not some yahoo site.

A solution:
Host a proxy script on some webserver, or write all of your code in PHP. Here is two great references on what a proxy script is, and the second link actually provides one for you:
[Link 1](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)
[Link 2](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/)

Any more help needed, you can let me know, I had to set one up myself, on my server, and I can help you out if you run into problems.

Comment: @ LostInTheCode : Sorry for not making the problem clear. I have made the changes in the text above to show what is going wrong.

Comment: window.location.reload() can be replaced with "history.go(0)" or "window.location.href=window.location.href"

Answer (score 1):

did you tried:

```
window.location = window.location;
```